# How to overlay a background gradient image on top of another infinite background image in CSS / HTML

Tags: html, overlay, background-image, css

So I am trying to discover how to overlay a gradient that repeats or extends across the entire bottom of the screen on top of checkered square that repeats infinitely. I can get a gradient to appear around the table that I have already written for the page, but it will not extend across the entire page.

What I have written below is about as far as I have gotten with this project. T'm kinda new to code so I'd appreciate any help y'all can give me.

`<style type="text/css">`

```
BODY{`background-image: url(image); repeat;}
div.wrapper {
background-image: url(image2.gradient); repeat-x fixed;
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
<table>
```

Then it goes on from there...

Answer (score 0):

Your `wrapper` div will only be as big as its contents, so you'll need to set height and width to 100% on your `wrapper` class.

```
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;      
  background: url(image2.gradient) repeat-x fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it encompass the entire page though? 

as of now, it only encompasses the table that I have on the page

Comment: Try setting `position: relative` on the div.

Comment: Also look at the change I made to your background style designation, you had the syntax wrong.  May want to try removing the fixed setting as well to see if that matters.